# Как запланировать выполнение кода на несколько заданных параметров времени (часы, минуты)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне необходимо написать код который будет работать на заданные кол-ва времени, (задаваться будет разное время (15:46, 17:23, 12:15)), я сделал так..., список часов, и список минут, по ним программа проверяет условие
(Я использовал именно datetime чтобы не возникло ошибок с вычитанием минут (например если они меньше 3)

```
h_list = [15, 17, 12, 11, 16]
m_list = [46, 23, 15, 26, 41]
index_day = len(h_list)

 while True:
        now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        now = now[11:19]
    
        for index in range(index_day):
            if now == str(datetime.timedelta(hours=h_list[index], minutes=m_list[index] - 3)):
                *#(job)*
```

Если ли другой способ проверки, чтобы пк не тратил большое кол-во ресурсов, для проверки каждого элемента списка?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136651/discussion-on-question-by-danya-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть `schedule`, есть `scheduler`. Советую ознакомиться с ними.
Например, полезная ссылка к данной задаче:
https://answacode.com/questions/11523918/python-zapusk-funkcii-v-zadannoe-vremya

А вот документация: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Я бы делал так вместо вашего кода
(но надо установить библиотеку https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule):

```
import schedule
import time

schedule.every().day.at("15:46").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("17:23").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("12:15").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("11:26").do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("16:41").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, сергей, а то я сам недавно начал в python работать (2-ой мес) сам изучаю, ну теперь буду знать, ах да одна вроде как ваша идея была, о расчете времени след точки и засыпании кода через time.sleep() , мне понравилась эта идея, будет время подумаю стоит ли ее реализовать, спасибо еще раз))

Comment: @Danya, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если сильно понравилось:-)  (Количество ответов с плюсами не ограничено, но принять можно только один).

Comment: Да мне помогло, но я все же доработаю ваш код, тем что сделаю удаление каждого расписания после того как работа кода будет выполнена (через документацию нашел) чтобы снизить потребление ресурсов, ну да, такой я человек))), а так же ради себя попробую написать альтернативу, программа будет засыпать на высчитанное кол-во секунд и добавлю их в решение :))

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал это так:

```py
from datetime import datetime


time_list = ["11:58", "12:00", "19:45"]

while True:
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    for i in time_list:
        if i == f'{current_datetime.hour}:{current_datetime.minute}':
            print(True)
            # Ваш алгоритм
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Все же лучше использовать уже имеющиеся библиотеки для таких проверок.

Comment: Я так сказать упростил код сверху:)

Comment: Спасибо вам :))

Comment: Дело в том что я не принялся изучать данный модуль, мельком глянул, и нашел "вроде как" рабочую идею но как оказалось (у меня есть мониторинг ОЗУ) выполнение кода занимает слишком много ОЗУ, и комп гудит, а он и так старенький, вот и пришел сюда с вопросом))))